# How to load DynamoDB tables from YAML template to Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, yaml

I'm testing a service that accesses dynamo DB tables, using test containers.
The necessary tables are being created in java test class before the tests run (partial code below) and everything works fine.

```
        CreateTableRequest request = new CreateTableRequest()
            .withTableName(TABLE_NAME)
            .withKeySchema(keySchema)
            .withAttributeDefinitions(attributeDefinitions)
            .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput()
                .withReadCapacityUnits(5L)
                .withWriteCapacityUnits(6L));

        Table table = dynamoDB.createTable(request);
        table.waitForActive();
```

However, the "real" tables are deployed to AWS via a cloudformation template (in YAML).

My question is: Is there any way to use that template on tests? I mean, import and create those tables from it and not with the code above?

Maybe via an AWS CLI command or some library that I could use to read the YAML file, and create the tables used for testing based on the template.

Searched a lot about this, and can't find anything in Java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question  - "t***hat I could use to read the YAML file, and create the tables*** "

To read YAML from Java, you would need to use a supported API - for example:

https://dzone.com/articles/read-yaml-in-java-with-jackson

Once you are able to read YAML, you can use the Java SDK for Java (preferably V2) to interact with the DynamoDB service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  
Yes, I can read the YAML, that is not the problem. But then how can I create the table with that, I mean, how can associate the YAML values to an AWS resource, in this case, a dynamo DB table? That is the main problem..

Comment: You need to use Java logic and the AWS SDK for Java. For example, read YAML - for example, to obtain the table name from the YAML file. Then pass that value to another Java method that uses the DynamoDB API to create the table. To create a DynamoDB table using the Java API V2 - see this example.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/dynamodb/src/main/java/com/example/dynamodb/CreateTable.java

Hope this helps...